# How to choose regex rule on TextField component using ternary operator?

Tags: reactjs

I have a TextField component that might receive two different types of documents (CPF or CNPJ). Each document has its format specifications:

CPF: XXX.XXX.XXX-XX

CNPJ: XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX

I've worked with regex and string replacement before and this is the way I do it:

```js
const regexCPF = /^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})$/;

...

<TextField
    value={values.cpf.replace(regexCPF, "$1.$2.$3-$4")}        
/>
```

I did hide a lot of properties just to emphasize the regex rule being used.

I've tried to use ternary operator like this:

```js
const regexCPF = /^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})$/;
const regexCNPJ = /^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{2})$/;

...

<TextField
    value={values.cpf.length < 12 ? values.cpf.replace(regexCPF, "$1.$2.$3-$4") : values.cpf.replace(regexCNPJ, "$1.$2.$3/$4-$5")}        
/>
```

I thought it would work but it didn't. I saw a couple ways of doing it on the internet like implementing a handleChange function but my code broke. Is there a way of doing it using the ternary operator?